# Android studio move check box to right of table cell

Tags: android, checkbox, textview

I have created a table view inside of a list view in Android studio (see following code) and for various reasons I have used a text view and a checkbox as separate elements rather than just having the checkbox and attaching the text. The problem is the text is on the left of the screen/table but the checkbox is essentially centred where as I want it to be at the far right hand side.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Button1"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:background="@drawable/list">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/Maths"
        android:id="@+id/Maths"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/MathsCheck"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:buttonTint="#00ffff"
            android:onClick="MathsClicked"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/History"
            android:id="@+id/History"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/HistoryCheck"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:onClick="HistoryClicked"
            android:buttonTint="#00ffff" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

There are in reality a lot more of these text view and checkboxes but you get the idea. I have tried using padding and margins but that doesn't really work as it will work ok on some devices displays but I have to hard code it which isn't ideal. I've also tried the gravity feature which for some reason doesn't seem to do anything.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason why you are using a TableLayout?
If not, the desired output (TextViews left-aligned, Checkboxes right-aligned) can be easily achieved with a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) within a vertical LinearLayout.

Your XML would then look like this (including only the relevant parts, all other attributes of your code will remain unchanged):

```
<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Edit**:
If you want to place multiple checkboxes next to each other, you can do so by making their position reference each other, like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/checkbox1" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/checkbox2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that you have to define the rightmost checkbox first, and the leftmost last.
Given the width of the checkboxes is identical (which they is in most cases), they will perfectly align.

Comment: I mean yes and no, it is feasible for me to implement the design I want to achieve with a vertical Linear layout, the thing is I may want to in future add several check boxes next to one textview and have some text views with for example 3 check boxes and some with 1 but the third ones always need to align and so it is for this reason I chose the table layout.

Comment: The scenario you mentioned can still be achieved using RelativeLayouts. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll look into it then report back